# CustomPouchError during replication between PouchDB and Cloudant

Tags: javascript, angular, pouchdb, cloudant

I am currently trying in an angular project to replicate a local database with PouchDB to a remote database hosted on Cloudant.

I have no problem with the replication from the local to the cloudant database but the replication doesn't work from the Cloudant to the local database.

I have the following error:

```
CustomPouchError {result: {…}}
  result:
    doc_write_failures: 0
    docs_read: 0
    docs_written: 0
    end_time: "2018-08-03T11:44:24.375Z"
    errors: []
    last_seq: 0
    ok: false
    start_time: "2018-08-03T11:44:24.019Z"
    status: "aborting"
  __proto__:
    Object
  __proto__:
    Error
```

I have no problem with credential to access to Cloudant.

Here is my code:

```
constructor() {


  this.dbRemote = new PouchDB(`${environment.URL_DB}/${environment.DB}`, {
    auth: {
      username: `${environment.USERNAME_DB}`,
      password: `${environment.PASSWORD_DB}`
    },
    skipSetup: true
  });

  this.db = new PouchDB(environment.DB);

  this.db.replicate.to(this.dbRemote, {retry: true}).on('complete', () => {
    this.db.replicate.from(this.dbRemote, {retry: true}).on('complete', () => {
      this.db.sync(this.dbRemote, {
        live: true,
        retry: true
      }).on('change', change => {
        this.handleChange(change);
      }).on('error', err => {
        console.error(`Sync error ${err}`);
      });
    }).on('paused', function (info) {
      console.info('From remote pause: ', info);
    }).on('error', err => {
      console.error(`Replication from remote error ${err}`);
    });
  }).on('paused', function (info) {
    console.info('To remote pause: ', info);
  }).on('error', err => {
    console.error(`Replication to remote error ${err}`);
  });
}
```

Note: I have enabled CORS on Cloudant.

Anyone have an idea to understand this error ?

Thanks

EDIT: I tried with an empty database and with one document, it works. The error only occurs when i try to replicate document with attachements.